# Parse TIF Files Client Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, webclient, tiff

I need to parse tiff files on the client, so using some JQuery library, JS or HTML5. I've searched and can't find exactly what I need. I can't use any server side technology or browser plugin. I've tried tiff.js https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js , but don't see a way to view individual pages or print a page range. Any help would be appreciated.

Bill

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parse tiff files on the client"? Display them? Extract Exif data?

Comment: Be able to view them, on a page by page basis, and print the individual pages or a range of pages. These are scan files, so they're CCITT 4 images.

Answer (score 3):

I made a tiny JS library [UTIF.js](https://github.com/photopea/UTIF.js) for parsing and encoding TIFFs. It can decode both CCITT 3 and CCITT 4 files. It supports multi-page files, too.

This library is used in my photo editor [Photopea](//www.photopea.com) to parse TIFF files on a client side (open your file in Photopea to see if UTIF.js can parse it).

Comment: I want to load a big tiff image that is stored on my local and display it on a html view. Do you have an example of something similar?